# DataBound controls don't save new values

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I've bound a lot of controls on a form to a Entity. Some of them update fine, the others are just jumping back to their original value as soon as it loses focus.

The old data are loaded in all controls perfectly.

```
Dim Q = From e In EnData.Calls Where e.CallID = ID
TempRow = Q.FirstOrDefault()

ticTemp1.DataBindings.Add("Value", TempRow, "CallDate")
ticTemp2.DataBindings.Add("Value", TempRow, "CustomerID")
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't got any answer how to make that work.

So I tried to use the designer to make the data binding, for some reason that did work correctly!.

So if you have problems with manually coded binding try to use the binding component generated by the designer.